Is this Samsung battery usage indicator broken?

idk if this site is right place place to ask the question, but i do not know how this "samsung battery usage indicator" works.
You can see from last charge(95%) it used 78% till now, and currently its (95-78) =17%. But if you add up the battry usage of individual apps given on bottom right i.e 25.6%+ 0.7% + 0.7% + 0.7% + 0.6% = 28.3%.
Why it doesn't add up to 78%? Its far less than that, even considering minimal background usage of system apps it would never reach 78%.  Where is most of my battery usage lost?
The Device is Samsung M55 8gb variant.
Specifications- https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m55-ampp-12896.php

@beeshyams Could you please tell anything, if you happen to know about the battery usage settings in samsung because it is a bit urgent and i need to get the phone replaced within 2 days if it turns out faulty.

I wish I could. I haven't used Samsung files for about 10 years and I am clueless. It's a good question and I upvoted it. All the best, hoping you get an answer in the time frame

Checking my non-gaming usage on Galaxy M12, the page showed 10% usage, but the total apps only summed up to 6.9%. I have a hunch that the rest was discharged due to heat while playing the game (probably that steep slope?), or idling (minimum/almost negligible).

The battery usage is an estimation. My guess is that the usage statistics is not designed to be sumed up so just interpret the total battery state and the app battery usage seperated. The values of the apps may be compared among each other so if one app has 5% and another 10% then the one has consumed twice the power compared to the other.
